# Is it possible to use optionals for members in structures or classes in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm having a difficulty reconciling my admittedly incomplete understanding of optionals and this from the Swift 2.1 documentation:

> Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an
>   appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or
>   structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an
>   indeterminate state.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
struct Name {
    var firstName = "Flintstone First"
    var middleName: String?
    var lastName = "Flintstone"
}

var wilmaHusband: Name
wilmaHusband.firstName = "Fred"
```

where *middleName* may be **nil**. However, quite understandably according to that part of the Swift documentation, I encounter the error *Struct wilmaHusband must be completely initialized before a member is stored...*

Is what I'm trying to do--make a member potentially **nil** in a structure (or class) impossible in Swift? If so, it seems one seeming advantage of optionals--that they may hold the kind of data that may or may not be present in a structured object (such as a middle name in a name construct)--is lost.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here in my understanding of optionals, and I apologize in advance for my naïveté.

Comment: How is `wilmaHusband` declared? Please provide a (short) *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem. – Optionals are implicitly initialized to `nil`, so this should work.

Comment: Whoops, sorry @MartinR, left out a line in my sample code. Thanks for catching that. Error thrown in Xcode 7 Playground.

Comment: Well, you have *declared* a variable `wilmaHusband` of type `Name`, but you have not *initialized* it ... – This has nothing to do with optionals.

Comment: @MartinR, that's the missing puzzle piece. I've taken a stab at initializing it a number of ways, all with errors, and none that leaves middleName nil. I'm an idiot. How would you initialize `wilmaHusband` of type `Name`?

Comment: Change to `var wilmaHusband = Name()`.

Comment: Just type `var wilmaHusband = Name(` and watch the auto-completion – there are two choices :)

Comment: Arrrrrrrgh @PaulGriffiths, as I said, I'm an idiot. Should I take this post down or leave it up?

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR, I love that autocompletion in the full Xcode IDE, but it doesn't seem to be fully implemented in the Playground.

Comment: @Dribbler: My tip is: If *anything* unexpected happens in the Playground, use a compiled project instead. The compiler diagnostics are often better.

Comment: @MartinR, perhaps I should change the title of this post to be, "when should I not use the Playground?" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *all* members of the `struct` have an initial value
(including `var middleName: String?` which – as an optional – is
implicitly initialized to `nil`), you can create a variable of that
type simply with

```
var wilmaHusband = Name()
```